# Asp.Net: How to Prevent double click of a button inside a ListView

Tags: asp.net

i would like to prevent double click of a button inside a ListView and an UpdatePanel. 
My source code is:

```
   <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSend" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
...

...

...

 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSend" Text="Send" CommandName="WriteFunc" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' OnClientClick="this.disabled='true';return true;" />
```

As you can see i use OnClientClick .. but it didn't work.
I suppose problem is the UpdatePanel and the asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting this on your 'page_init' event:

```
this.btnSend.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "this.disabled='true'; return true;");
```